# Flink Datastream check if message exists in postgresDB before sinking

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-flink

I have a flink code which uses flink datastream API to read messages from kafka and sink those to a PostgresDB.

I want to sink the kafka messages to the database only if that message does not exist in the db. If the message exists, I need to update only the database column which has changed for the incoming message.

As per the documentation, the jdbc sink takes in a DML Statement.

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's likely two ways to achieve this, both with varying levels of introduced latency, one being a filtering function prior to the sink, and the other being handled on the Postgres side as an upsert operation.

##### Filtering Approach (introduces latency)

The filtering function would add considerable latency as it'd have to explicitly hit the database for each record to check for its existence:

```
yourStream
   .filter(CustomFunctionToQueryPostgres())
   .sinkTo(yourPostgresSink)
```

Where the `CustomFunctionToQueryPostgres()` function would contain a client that could issue the statement to Postgres, read the result, and continue to the sink (or in the cases where it exists - drop it on the floor).

##### Upsert Approach (more Postgres overhead)

Another possibly more elegant approach would be to introduce an upsert procedure that could wrap your logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_record(...)

BEGIN        
    // Handle new records
    INSERT INTO records 
    SELECT ...
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT some_unique_constraint DO
        UPDATE
           // Handle existing records
END;
```

And then calling that function from your sink that handles writing to Postgres:

```
object UpsertPostgresSink {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    fun build(): SinkFunction<YourRecord> {
        val sql = "SELECT upsert_record(?, ?)"
        val statement = { statement: PreparedStatement, record: YourRecord ->
            ...
            statement.setObject(1, ...)
            statement.setString(2, ...)
        }


        return JdbcSink
            .sink(
                sql,
                statement,
                JdbcExecutionOptions.builder().build(),
                JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                    .withDriverName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                    .withUrl(yourConnectionString)
                    .build(),
            )
    }
}
```

And then just call that from your pipeline:

```
yourStream
   .sinkTo(UpsertPostgresSink.build())
```